# How to do one line flag embed in PyTorch (not nn.Embedding)?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, embedding

With a generator I create the random batch like:

```py
import torch

n = 10
batch_size = 2

x = torch.zeros((batch_size, n), dtype=torch.float)
in_flags = torch.randint(n, (batch_size,), dtype=torch.long)

for idx, row in enumerate(x):
    row[in_flags[idx]] = 1.0
```

But the disadvantage of that is that loop runs in Python.
That is the original meaning of embedding (do not confuse that with PyTorch nn.embedding). Is it possible to do with one PyTorch operator to make it be executed native or in GPU?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```py
import torch

n = 10
batch_size = 2

in_flags = torch.randint(n, (batch_size,), dtype=torch.long)
x = torch.zeros((batch_size, n), dtype=torch.float)

# this is how you can do this
x[torch.arange(batch_size), in_flags] = 1.0

print(in_flags)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
tensor([8, 0])
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```